# YouTube Gdata No Average Rating in Python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, attributeerror

This works perfectly when finding the average rating and number of raters for a youtube video.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from gdata.youtube.service import YouTubeService

yt = YouTubeService()
entry = yt.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=sys.argv[1])
dir(entry.rating)
['FindExtensions', 'ToString', '_AddMembersToElementTree', '_BecomeChildElement', '_ConvertElementAttributeToMember', '_ConvertElementTreeToMember', '_HarvestElementTree', '_ToElementTree', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', '_children', '_namespace', '_tag', 'average', 'extension_attributes', 'extension_elements', 'max', 'min', 'num_raters', 'text']
print entry.rating.average
print entry.rating.num_raters
```

but when the video has no rating it throws an error.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'average'

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gd:rating is deprecated 
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_gd:rating

Anyway you should check if raiting exists

```
if entry.rating:
    print entry.rating.average
    print entry.rating.num_raters
else:
    print 'entry has no rating'
```

Comment: `YouTubeService()` is a version 1 client. It always receives `gd:rating`.

Comment: Thank you! http://code.google.com/p/python-youtube-datascraper/source/browse/youtube.py